# How to change the default register table

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am trying to change the default table for the register and login feature. I created the auth with Laravel. I've tried changing the guards in the config/auth.php. But when I try to load the register page I get the error:

```
Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct(): Argument #2 ($provider) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given
```

Here's my auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'password' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'Utilisateur',
            'table' => 'Utilisateurs',
        ],
    ],
```

The name of my Model is Utilisateur and the name of my table is Utilisateurs in my database.

I tried changing the auth.php, I also changed the validators with my Utilisateurs table. Nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/auth.php` put the `model` inside providers section:

```
 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => \App\Models\Users\User::class,
        ],
        
    ],
```